# SQL Server Agent Job - Runtime error The server principal "ABC" is not able to access the database "XYZ"

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with a SQL Server Agent Job run time error:

SQL Server Agent Job - Runtime error The server principal "ABC" is not able to access the database "XYZ" under the current security context. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 916).  The step failed.

I know there are similar questions here but not necessarily related to SQL Server Agent Jobs ..

I have reviewed various web articles but not yet succeeded in resolving ..

The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/the-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-under-the-current-security-context-urgent

[The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context in SQL Server MS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009488/the-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-under-the-current-securi)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/overview-of-sql-server-security

Am running job as a specified user IAM-Replication.

Answer (score 1):

try to create a database user for the login/server principal and grant "enough" permissions to see if the job works.

```
--The server principal "ABC" is not able to access the database "XYZ" under the current security context. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 916). The step failed.

use XYZ --<-- put the db name here
go

--create a database user for the server principal "ABC"
create user dbuserforABC for login ABC
go

--overly grant permissions to dbuserforABC
alter role db_owner add member dbuserforABC --better revise the dbuser permissions, use this just for poc/troubleshooting
go

--try the job again
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do when this doesn't work and I still get this same error / issue? Maybe a sql*server 2017 bug / issue ?

Comment: If I google for "SQL Server Agent Job - Runtime error The server principal is not able to access the database" I get half million results ... so this must be a commonly occurring issue.

Comment: I spotted this article : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c874e3d-b39d-494e-be12-e3d72c3a73b2/the-server-principal-quotxxxxxxquot-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-quotdataxxxxxquot?forum=sqlsecurity      likewise .. If I remove the "run as" in the job then it works .. hmmm ... I had tried all the same heavy handed security steps also ..

Comment: the accepted answer in the article you have spotted provides the reason/explanation why you get the error. When you set the "run as"  this equates to : execute as user = " IAM-Replication" (== impersonation). When you impersonate a dbuser, you can work only in the context/scope of one/single database. If you try to access another database (or execute a module on another database) you get the infamous: "The current principal cannot...under the current security context" error. Current security context=impersonation.

Comment: you can use impersonation (run as when talking about an agent job) and access another database (from the current database) if you ALTER curerntdb SET TRUSTWORTHY ON which is a "BAD" security practice and you really do not have to do that. You could try testing with TRUSTWORTHY and check if it works (for educational reasons), however, you should ask: Do i need to impersonate/run as IAM-Replication? Most likely you do not need to.