# Allow application role to perform DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, application-role

My (C#) application runs, connecting to an SQL server database with an Application Role.

However, I need it to run a `DBCC CHECKDB`, but I get an exception:

> User 'MyAppRole' does not have permission to run DBCC checkdb for database 'MyDatabase'.

I found out that to run this command, I can't just grant permission to the Application Role to perform this action, I need to be a member of the `db_owner` role.

**Things I've Tried:**

1: 
In SQL Management Studio, ticking the db_owner box in the properties of MyAppRole for this database. However I get the same exception.

2: Add db_owner role.

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyAppRole'
```

But now when I run the application I get this exception at the point of doing the DBCC CHECKDB:

> The server principal "MYDOMAIN\MyWindowsUsername" is not able to access the database "MyDatabase" under the current security context.

which is especially confusing because in SQL Managment Studio, I can easily run the command, after logging in using Windows Authentication.

3: creating a stored procedure with execute as Owner

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dbcccheck WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKDB (MyDatabase) WITH TABLERESULTS
END
GO
```

... and given my `MyAppRole` *execute* Permission.  But I still get the exception:

> The server principal "MYDOMAIN\MyWindowsUsername" is not able to access the database "MyDatabase" under the current security context.

...which I also get if I try to execute this stored procedure from SQL Management Studio.

4: Give Application Role "CONTROL" permission (some of these would seem to defeat the purpose of an application role but anyway, grasping at straws)

```
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::MyDatabase TO MyAppRole
```

but this results in the original error when the application tries to run the check.

> User 'MyAppRole' does not have permission to run DBCC checkdb for database 'MyDatabase'

How do I correctly give my application role permission to do this check?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions)

> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role or the db_owner fixed database role.

The issue you are having as a result of step 1 might be because the windows user is not mapped to the database you are connecting to.

Comment: When I view the properties of this (Windows) Login, I see that "Map" is ticked for this database, but the "User" is dbo. If I try to change this I get an error saying `Cannot alter the user 'dbo'`. BTW the Windows login is a sysadmin on the server.

Comment: @colmde Try - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471124/t-sql-to-list-all-the-user-mappings-with-database-roles-permissions-for-a-login/9356725#9356725 to confirm list of roles/permissions.  You need to grant the permissions to the correct mapped user/group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not `SQL Server` DBA expert, but I'm posting my experience.

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) `DBCC CHECKDB` commnad requires `sysadmin` fixed server role or the `db_owner` fixed database role. Since application role can't be a member of `sysadmin` role we can consider only the second option.

We want to operate with a current database, hence we don't need server-level permissions and database-level permissions should be enough. Thus `db_owner` membership should do the trick and it works perfectly for the database user but for some reason it **doesn't work** for the **application role**.

I tried to add all other db roles for app role, checked user mappings that looked good, even tried to execute `DBCC TRACEON (4616, -1);` that is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-2017), but it also didn't help, server continued to throw error from your second paragraph.

I managed to make it work only by enabling `guest` user for current DB, but it breaks the idea of the application role.

I made a conclusion (not sure it is correct) that it is not possible and used regular `db role` and `db users` instead